# $_GET not working when trying to view php image in a lightbox style

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I have something that im currently working on, however it appears that the $_GET doesn't completely work.

I have a JavaScript light box that brings up an image in a little window, this works however i can only guess that it is using the same URL over and over again.

However when i view the source for the page (and even click one of the links in the source) it will display the correct data.

But the lightbox only seems to display the first image.

This is the JavaScript

```
<script>
//Checkes if any key pressed. If ESC key pressed it calls the lightbox_close() function.
window.document.onkeydown = function (e)
{
if (!e){
    e = event;
}
if (e.keyCode == 27){
    lightbox_close();
}
}
</script>

<script>
//This script makes light and fade divs visible by setting their display properties to        block. 
//Also it scrolls  the browser to top of the page to make sure, the popup will be on  middle of the screen.
function lightbox_open(){
window.scrollTo(0,0);
document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';  
}
</script>

<script>
//This makes light and fade divs invisible by setting their display properties to none.
function lightbox_close(){
document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
}
</script>
```

I wont show the CSS i dont think thats relivant (If someone wants it then ask away)

The relevant part that creates the links is this, its part of a ForEach statement all PHP

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($nrows as $nrow)
{
$id = $nrow['id'];
$rid = $nrow['RaidID'];
$bid = $nrow['BossID'];
$normal = $nrow['NormalKills'];
$heroic = $nrow['HeroicKills'];
$boss = substr($nrow['BossName'], 0, 3);
$p1 = $id + $bid.".php";
$image = $boss . $p1;

#echo $image;
echo $bid;

if ($oid != $rid)
{
$i = 0;
}
if ($i == 0) {

?><td style="width: 176px;"><center><b><?php echo $nrow['raid']; ?> </b></center></td> </tr><?php
$i++;
}
?><tr><td style="width: 176px;"><div align="left"><a href="#"     onclick="lightbox_open();"><?php echo $nrow['BossName']; ?></a><div id="light"><img     src="bossdata/template.php?boss=<?php echo $bid;?>"></a></div><div id="fade"     onClick="lightbox_close();"></div>
</div>
<?php 
if ($heroic == 0) 
{ 
if ($normal > 0) 
{
echo '<img src="images/whiteskull.png" align="right" alt="Normal Kill">';
} 
else 
{ 
echo '<img src="images/redx.png" align="right" alt="Not Killed">';
} 
}
else
{
echo '<img src="images/redskull.png" align="right" alt="Normal Kill">'; 
}
?>
</td></tr><?php
$oid = $id;
}
```

Now this all works, and it actually displays an image with data, however no matter what link i click the boss data is always from the first one on the list.

To me this means that the data is getting through, and reaching the the right parts on image so its "Working", but all the links do the same thing and show the same data :(

*Removed last code Bulk

Comment: Read this: [JavaScript is not Java](http://kb.mozillazine.org/JavaScript_is_not_Java).

Comment: This question has a relatively large amount of code with it.  Is it all relevant?  You'll be more likely to get feedback quickly if you can narrow the problem down to a smaller chunk of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple div with the same ID "light" since you create them in a foreach loop.

```
<div id="light">
```

Your function lightbox_open() opens all the divs that have id "light".

```
document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
```

That's why you always see the first lightbox. Because the others are behind the first one.

you should try something like this :

```
function lightbox_open(elem){
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
    elem.getElementByClass('light').style.display='block';
    elem.getElementByClass('fade').style.display='block';  
}
```

And change this :

```
<a href="#"     onclick="lightbox_open();">
```

By this :

```
<a href="#"     onclick="lightbox_open(this);">
```

And replace id by class in your div definition :

```
<div class="light">
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense, in a way. I can now at least understand why its doing what its doing, unfortunately your suggestion did not work, the lightbox seems to no longer function and it just imbeds the images into page. But it gives me something to look at thanks

Answer (score 0):

$_GET is working correctly in your code.

The issue is in the way you are combining JavaScript and PHP in the second code box. First, all of your divs have the same ID: "light" which is wrong because they all IDs are meant to be unique within the HTML document. You need to identify them uniquely, for example appending the BossID to them.

After identifying each div uniquely you'll have to edit lightbox_open and lightbox_close so they can receive the BossID of the divs that you want to show and hide.